# scroll down in appium robot framework

Tags: automated-tests, appium, robotframework, appium-android, appium-desktop

I have problem during use **Scroll Down** in appium  .

```
Scroll Down       xpath=//android.view.ViewGroup/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout[2]/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.TextView
```

but i got erorr response

```
VerifyPayType                                                         | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: Unknown mobile command "scroll". Only shell commands are supported.
```

Could anyone suggest me to scroll down in appuim by another method ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Scroll** Locator 2 Locator 1.

Example:

```
Scroll xpath=//*[@content-desc='Phone'] xpath=//*[@content-desc='Hangouts']
```

Note: Argument 1 is the element which is below argument 2.